# SharePoint 2013 - HTML page layout wouldn't update the aspx file in visual studio

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, branding

I've made a wsp package from design manager and imported it into visual studio.

When I'm editing the html page layouts the aspx file doesn't get updated.. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it like that. Visual Studio will not convert your HTML design files into .aspx. You can only do that conversion through SharePoint's Design Manager functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you need real-time converting html to aspx, you can [map network drive to masterpages folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj733519.aspx), open and edit html file. Aspx file will be updated right after saving html.

Comment: Yes, and you could probably go ahead and add those two files in your project as links, pointing to the mapped network drive. In the Add Existing Item dialog box, select the Add As Link operation instead of Add. You find it in the dropdown menu inside the Add button.